# JAXB - XmlElement with multiple types

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm working with jaxb and with xml I'm doing jpa. I had such a question. I keep a list of records in the Catalog. Previously, it was a list from a particular entity, but now I want to be able to do any entity. Tell me how can I do this?
I want to specify in the root element a class with an entity and somehow apply this to the list

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;


    @XmlAttribute(name = "class")
    private String className;

    @XmlElement(name = "record")
    private List<Book> recordList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    <--Getters and Setters-->
```

This my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<catalog id="1" type="extendable" class="cataloghandler.entities.Books">
    <record>
        <title>book1</title>
        <description>hello12345</description>
    </record>

    <record>
        <title>book2</title>
        <description>goodbye</description>
    </record>
</catalog>
```

And I want to add another Entity, for example, TVShow, with another fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<catalog id="6" type="extendable" class="cataloghandler.entities.TVShow">
    <record>
        <channel>fox</channel>
        <time>10:45</time>
    </record>

     <record>
        <channel>abc</channel>
        <time>12:00</time>
    </record>
</catalog>
```

How I can change code so, that List have type `List<TVShow>`.

Comment: I think, that can do it with XmlAdapter, but i can' t understand, how i can get attribute "class" from <catalog>

Comment: Well, i think it also can do by XMlAttributes({}), but I want to do like open-close, no change this class if i wil have new entities